# How to read a private video on youtube with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, video, youtube

Everything's in the title. I'm doing an e-learning platform and i'm trying to read a private youtube video with my Symfony application. 
When I put my link into my iframe, I got a 'youtube.com blocked the connexion'.

Does someone have any idea ?

Comment: I think you can't do this ! Google says : ``Private videos can only be seen by people who have been invited to view the video.`` (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/77272?hl=en)

Comment: I might be wrong. But I think vimeo is better suited for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it with Loom, it's kinda secured cause u can only DL pieces of video (4-5 sec max).